# How to Use Cookies with Go App Engine Urlfetch Package

Tags: google-app-engine, cookies, https, go

This code works fine with regular Go code.

```
cookieJar, err := cookiejar.New(nil)
// error handling
client := &http.Client{Jar: cookieJar}

// authenticate request
authUrl := "https://some_secure_site"
values := make(url.Values)
values.Set("login_email", "email")
values.Set("login_password", "password")
resp, err := client.PostForm(authUrl, values)
// handle error

// process resp
```

I need to do something similar in App Engine using Go.  App Engine uses urlfetch package instead of http package.

How do I use urlfetch package to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`urlfetch.Client` returns a  `*http.Client`

```
func Client(context appengine.Context) *http.Client
```

so simply set the Jar in the created client

```
client := urlfetch.Client(c)
client.Jar = cookieJar
...
```